# My tree program crashes after inserting into one root node

Tags: c, recursion, tree, binary-search-tree

I am not too good at making trees and I totally screw up recursion. However, I attempted to make a program to insert and display data into the tree.

The problem is that it crashes after inserting into the root node and I do not know why. The tree is not too big. Just 10 `int`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 10;
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node * left;
    struct node * right;
};


void insert(struct node * root,int num){
    printf("Insert called for num:%d\n",num);
    if(root == NULL){
        root = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        root->data = num;
    }else if(num > root->data){ // Number greater than root ?
        insert(root->right,num); // Let the right sub-tree deal with it
    }else if(num < root->data){// Number less than root ?
        insert(root->left,num);// Let the left sub-tree deal with it.
    }else{
        // nothing, just return.
    }
}


void display(struct node * root){ // Inorder traversal
    if(root->left!=NULL){ // We still have children  in left sub-tree ?
        display(root->left); // Display them.
    }

    printf("%d",root->data); // Display the root data

    if(root->right!=NULL){ // We still have children in right sub-tree ?
        display(root->right); // Display them.
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a[10] = {2,1,3,5,4,6,7,9,8,10};
    int i;
    struct node * tree;

    for(i = 0; i < 10;i++){
        insert(tree,a[i]);
    }
    printf("Insert done");
    return 0;
}
```

**Can someone please tell me where I went wrong ?**

I know it is frowned upon to ask people to review your code on Stack but sometimes [pair programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_programming) works :p

**Update:**
After setting `struct node * tree = NULL;`, the `insert()` method works well. The `display()` causes program to crash.

Comment: I immediately see on problem. you never initialize your root node `left` and `right` pointers to NULL after the allocation. The passing of `root` by-val Grijesh already covered, so i won't.

Comment: @LittleChild Actually two mistakes pointer by me and WhoCraig and one more posted below. check your code care fully

Comment: @WhozCraig Aren't they initialized to NULL bu default ?

Comment: @LittleChild No. `malloc()` simply allocates memory. the content is indeterminate until *you* initialize it after the allocation. Likewise with local vars (and Crashworks points this out in an answer below).

Comment: Local variables, and data allocated of the heap, are never initialized. You have to do that explicitly, either by assigning to variables or structure members, or when allocating of the heap use [`calloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg So, sir, what you are saying is that i should switch to `calloc` instead of `malloc` if I want them to be initialized to default values ?

Comment: @LittleChild Yes, that makes all the allocated memory zero. Also don't forget to initialize local variables, like in the case pointed out to you by Crashworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // ...
    struct node * tree;
    // what is the value of tree at this line?
    for(i = 0; i < 10;i++){
        insert(tree,a[i]);
    }
    // ...
}
```

what does "tree" point to at the line marked?

Comment: `tree` points to the root node of the tree. I named it `tree` simply. :)

Comment: No, I mean, at that line: What is contained in the 'tree' variable? If you did printf("%x\n",tree);, what would you see?

Comment: Null. At first, the root node is supposed to be null.

Comment: What makes 'tree' NULL?

Comment: Nothing. I did not `malloc` it so it is sitting there, vacant.

Comment: You see, I am sorry if I am asking noobish questions. I am used to the idea that variables are always intialized to some default values (blame Java for this) :)

Comment: You didn't initialize 'tree' either. Remember that pointers are variables also. (As far as the CPU is concerned, a pointer is an unsigned integer containing an address.) If you do not initialize a variable, it contains some garbage value. Therefore 'tree' points to a random address.

Comment: I did heed your advise and `insert()` now works well. Display crashes the program :)

Comment: @LittleChild its *indeterminate*. I.e. its "value" is undefined until it is initialized, and therefore cannot be legally even evaluated. There are three major things wrong with your code, and all of them have been touched on in either comments or this answer. This, the comments about failure to initialize `left` and `right` after `malloc()` in `insert()`, and failure to pass the root parameter by-address (a pointer-to-pointer) or return the new root as a function return.

Comment: @LittleChild that will work (another way is to pass the pointer by address and declare the function parameter to be a pointer-to-pointer type). Also, ou may want to free that memory when you're done, but you may not have covered post-order traversals yet, which is the right way to free a binary-tree. Regardless, it looks like you're there, so glad to help.

Comment: @WhozCraig I am glad you guys invested your precious time in solving my problem so quickly. I was working on this last night and couldn't figure out what was wrong. :)